# Is there a way to purposely turn off all anti-aliasing for UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-graphics

I'm trying to make a kind of old-looking app, and so as a result I want my UIView's to be rendered without anti-aliasing. In other words I want my views to be pixelized ,especially the `view.layer.cornerRadius`, as in this case I am able to layout my views using AutoLayout.

This would make it much easier than drawing different pixel arts for different iPhone sizes. Moreover, if I did draw the pixel art whenever a view is resized I would have to create a new pixel art as scaling the images vould distort the pixel art.

The only thing that I have found is `view.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing` which by default is already set to false. I was also thinking to use the Core Graphic's `BeizerPaths` to draw the pixelized shadows and corners, would this be a viable way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Your best bet is to create appropriate assets for this purpose.

Comment: Agree.  Anti-aliasing isn't the real problem.  If you want the 8-bit look of a minecraft, you should build custom cells and provide your own image assets for everything.

Comment: Alright, I was afraid that that would be the answer, thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable anti-aliasing in UIKit (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72823895/disable-anti-aliasing-in-uikit-swift)

Answer (score 1):

You can go down to the Core Graphics CGContext and friends, and you can specifically tell the Graphics Context to shut off anti-aliasing, with CGContextSetShouldAntialias(context, false);

Here are two small screen grabs, one with no jaggies, and the other with jaggies.

[image: First Image With No Jaggies]

[image: Second Image WIth Jaggies]